Skipping the specified stage in pipeline
I created new pipeline.yml file which run creates several resources with Terraform. When they are already created the specific stage should be omit and than only the current state is checking.
    parameters:
      - name: myConn
        type: string
        default: 'dev'
    
    variables:
    - group: dev-group
    - name: workingDirectory
      value: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/configs'
    
    stages:
      - stage: Just_printing
        displayName: 'Printing some variables'
        jobs:
          - job: PrintJobs
            displayName: 'Print Job'
            steps:   
              - script: |
                  echo "printing directory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
                  cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
                  ls -lha $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    
              - script: |
                  echo "printing directory: $(workingDirectory)"
                  cd $(workingDirectory)
                  ls -lha $(workingDirectory)
     
    
      - stage: Deployment
        displayName: 'Terraform deploy'
        dependsOn: 
          - Just_printing
        jobs:
          - deployment: terraform
            environment:
              name: dev
            pool: "server"
            strategy:
              runOnce:
                deploy:
                  steps:
                  - task: ManualValidation@0
                    timeoutInMinutes: 1440
                    inputs:
                      notifyUsers: |
                          dev@test.com
                      instructions: "approving..."
                      onTimeout: "reject"
    
          - job: "TerraformApprove"
            displayName: "Deployment ..."
            dependsOn: terraform
            steps:            
              - task: TerraformCLI@0
                displayName: 'Terraform Init'
                inputs:
                  command: init
                  backendType: gcs
                  backendGcsCredentials: ${{ parameters.myConn}}
                  backendGcsBucket: 'dev-state'
                  workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
    
    
              - task: TerraformCLI@0
                displayName: 'Terraform Plan'
                name: plan
                inputs:
                  command: plan
                  publishPlanResults: 'TerraformPlan'
                  workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
                  commandOptions: '-out=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/configs/tf.tfplan'
                  providerGoogleCredentials: ${{ parameters.myConn}}
    
              - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1  
                displayName: 'Publish Terraform Plan'
                inputs:
                  pathtoPublish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/configs/tf.tfplan'
                  artifactName: 'Plan'
    
              - task: TerraformCLI@0
                displayName: 'Terraform Apply'
                inputs:
                  command: apply
                  workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
                  commandOptions: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/configs/tf.tfplan'
                  providerGoogleCredentials: ${{ parameters.myConn}}
    
      - stage: Just_state
        displayName: 'Just_state'
        dependsOn: Deployment
        jobs:
          - job: Just_state
            displayName: 'Just state Job'
            steps:
              - task: TerraformCLI@0
                displayName: 'Terraform Init'
                inputs:
                  command: init
                  backendType: gcs
                  backendGcsCredentials: ${{ parameters.myConn}}
                  backendGcsBucket: 'dev-state'
                  workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
                  commandOptions: '-reconfigure'
    
              - task: TerraformCLI@0
                displayName: 'terraform state list'
                inputs:
                  command: state
                  workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
                  stateSubCommand: list
                  commandOptions: '-state=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/configs/tf.tfstate'

I would like to skip the whole Deployment stage, when terraform checks that there were not changes in resource until the last pipeline run. I am not sure how to achieve that.
Tried with the bash script on Just_printing stage which only check if changes were made, and if not skip the whole Deployment stage, however it generated plenty error on my side and I stuck. Lastly it only checks at  Just_state stage the current deployed resources.
EDIT 1.
Added according to the below reply however each my change cause different errors. Generally it leads to the issue with credentials, but I do not how to pass it in that provided script.
The current error when I run that pipeline is::

Initializing the backend... │ Error: google: could not find default
credentials. See
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc for
more information

Code snippet for pipeline.yaml
- job: CheckChanges
  displayName: 'Check Changes'
  steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Check resource changes'
      name: setvar
      inputs:
        backendType: gcs
        backendGcsCredentials: ${{ parameters.myConn}}
        backendGcsBucket: 'dev-state'
        workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          cd $(workingDirectory)
          terraform init -reconfigure -backend-config="bucket=dev-state" -backend-config="impersonate_service_account=xxx@yyy.com"
          terraform plan -input=false -no-color -detailed-exitcode
          retVal=$?
          if [ $retVal -eq 2 ]; then
              echo "##vso[task.setvar variable=deploy;isOutput=true]true"
          else
              echo "##vso[task.setvar variable=deploy;isOutput=true]false"
          fi

  - stage: Deployment
    displayName: 'Terraform deploy'
    dependsOn: Just_printing
    condition: eq(dependencies.Just_printing.outputs['CheckChanges.setvar.deploy'], 'true')
    jobs:
      - deployment: terraform

FYI:

For or $(workingDirectory) I have set path in variables as $(sourceDirectory)/terraform where I have all my .tf file (main.tf, variables.tf), and $(sourceDirectory) keeps all yml like pipeline.yaml. It should be like that.
For ${{ parameters.myConn}} I keep the key directly in Azure DevOps. It also works in this way for all Deployment stage.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75889916/terraform-in-a-pipeline-how-to-check-for-plan-changes

I will try, give me several days. Thanks anyway for really quick update.

Hi @Kreg, have you tried the yaml below? Did it work for you?

Thank you @ZiyangLiu-MSFT for the first and quick reply. I replied in EDIT 1 since there is too much text for comment.

In my actual test, I am using a service principle for authentication with Azure and use azurerm backend. I have updated my answer below for your reference.

As mentioned in this question, you can use -detailed-exitcode option in terraform plan to check if there is any change. According to Command: plan,

-detailed-exitcode - Returns a detailed exit code when the command exits. When provided, this argument changes the exit codes and their meanings to provide more granular information about what the resulting plan contains:

0 = Succeeded with empty diff (no changes)
1 = Error
2 = Succeeded with non-empty diff (changes present)


Then create an output variable, in my example below it's deploy, to control whether to run Deployment stage. When the value of retVal is 2, set the value of deploy to true. Otherwise, set it to false.
In stage Deployment, use condition to control that the stage will run only when the value of deploy is true.
stages:
- stage: Just_printing
  displayName: 'Printing some variables'
  jobs:
  - job: CheckChanges
    displayName: 'Check Changes'
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Check resource changes'
      name: setvar
      env: 
        ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ parameters.clientId }}
        ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(clientSecret)
        ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ parameters.tenantId }}
        ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ parameters.deploymentSubscriptionId }}
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          terraform init -backend-config="resource_group_name={resource group which holds my storage account}" -backend-config="storage_account_name={storage account name}" -backend-config="container_name={container name}" -backend-config="key=terraform.tfstate" -backend-config="subscription_id={Sub id}"
          terraform plan -input=false -no-color -detailed-exitcode
          retVal=$?
          if [ $retVal -eq 2 ]; then
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=deploy;isOutput=true]true"
          else
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=deploy;isOutput=true]false"
          fi

- stage: Deployment
  displayName: 'Terraform deploy'
  dependsOn: Just_printing
  condition: eq(dependencies.Just_printing.outputs['CheckChanges.setvar.deploy'], 'true')
  jobs:
  - deployment: terraform
...

In the sample above, I am using a service principle for authentication with Azure and storing the credential as Environment Variables. (For security reasons, ARM_CLIENT_SECRET is provided through the secret variable clientSecret) You can also provide credential in your provider block. See Authenticating using a Service Principal with a Client Secret for the details. Ensure your service principle has enough permission to deploy your target resource. You can assign it Contributor role of your Sub.
I am using azurerm backend and configure it in the command. You can also configure backend in backend "azurerm" block. See example here Example Backend Configurations.
